# I'm stuck on how to make a sorting algorithm in a doubly linked list using a person's first name and last name in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, doubly-linked-list

So I made a doubly linked list which stores a person's first name, last name, address and age and I am currently stuck on making a sorting algorithm for the list. So far I've managed to create 3 functions, one that adds a node to the list, one that deletes a node from the list and one which prints the list.
Here's what I have so far, the struct:

```
    struct Node {
    string First_Name;
    string Last_Name;
    string Address;
    int age;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;
} *first = 0, * last = 0;
```

The addToList function:

```
void addToList()
{
    string temp = "Yes";
    string First_Name;
    string Last_Name;
    string Address;
    int age;
    Node* current = first;

    while (temp == "Yes") {

        cout << "Enter the persons first name: ";
        cin >> First_Name;
        cout << "Enter the persons last name: ";
        cin >> Last_Name;
        cout << "Enter the persons age: ";
        cin >> age;
        cout << "Enter the persons address: ";
        cin >> Address;
        cout << "Would you like to add another person? Yes or No";
        cin >> temp;

        current = new Node;
        current->First_Name = First_Name;
        current->Last_Name = Last_Name;
        current->age = age;
        current->Address = Address;
        if (last) last->next = current;
        else first = current;
        current->prev = last;
        current->next = 0;
        last = current;
    }
    return;
}
```

And the print list:

```
void printList()
{
    if (!first)
    {
        cout << "Nothing is present in the list." << endl;
        return;
    }
    Node* current = first;
    while (current)
    {
        cout << current->First_Name << " " << current->Last_Name << " " << current->age << " " << current->Address << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
```

My question is, how would I be able to sort the list alphabetically, I've never done sorting before...
Thank you!!

Comment: I would suggest that you start by making a function that can swap the position of 2 nodes.

Comment: A lot of homework about sorting linked lists. `std::sort` can't sort a `std::list` because it's just an unnecessarily painful experience (really because `std::list` doesn't provide the correct iterator type, but it was all done done on purpose). I feel like that makes for a poor homework. Sorts and runtime efficiency can be discussed with the proper data structures, and a linked list can be learned without the need to sort it.

Comment: Yes...I am aware to be fair....I know it's a poor idea and just inefficient overall but apparently my teacher goddamn likes it :)) it's for one of my assignments due this week and I'm officially stuck on how to do it, she wants us to do it but she hasn't exactly explained how...

Comment: Linked list is the hump mission of first-year programming. Adding sorting to it is just plain mean.

Comment: Suggestion: Separate the Linked List from the data it contains. This division of responsibility results in a much simpler linked list and data-management class and allows you to focus on one problem at a time. You can get a node, run the data class's `operator <` on the data in the node without either class getting in the other's way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use custom sorting for a doubly-linked list, overload `operator<`:

```
struct Person
{
  std::string first;
  std::string last;
  std::string address;
  unsigned int age;
  bool operator<(const Person& p) const
  {
      bool is_less_than = false;
      if (last == p.last)
      {
          is_less_than = first < p.first;
      }
      else
      {
          is_less_than = last < p.last;
      }
      return is_less_than;
  }
};
```

Now you can use `std::list` and it will automatically sort by last name, then first.  And `std::list` is a doubly-linked list.

To compare `Person`s:

```
  Person a;
  Person b;
  //...
  if (a < b)
  {
     std::cout << "Person A < Person B\n";
  }
```

Comment: Just one more question, so, how would I be able to use std::list, how do I initialize it, or rather, how do I implement it? I'm still a little confused... I hope I'm not wasting too much time...I'm just a newbie when it comes to sorting stuff

Comment: I find reference material very useful: [`std::list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list).

Comment: `std::list<Person> contacts;`  [`contacts.push_back(p);`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/push_back)